# Adding a label or name to volume in docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to find volume by label or name easily not by a docker assigned id like:

```
docker volume ls --filter label=key=value
```

but if I try add a 'container_name' or 'labels' to docker-compose.yaml I can't see any assigned label of name to volume when I inspect it, here is an output:

```
>>> docker volume inspect <volume_id>
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2020-10-28T11:41:51+01:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/4dce13df34f4630b34fbf1f853f7b59dbee2e3150a5122fa38d02024c155ec7d/_data",
        "Name": "4dce13df34f4630b34fbf1f853f7b59dbee2e3150a5122fa38d02024c155ec7d",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

I believe I can filter volumes by labels and name.

Here is a part of docker-compose.yml config file for mongo service:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: some_name
    image: mongo
    labels:
      com.docker.compose.project: app-name  
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./mongo:/data/db
```

Comment: You can add [`labels:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#labels-3) in the top-level `volumes:` block; what you've shown is a bind mount, not a volume mount, and that won't show up in `docker volume ls` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're tring to acheive here, but I hope something in my response will be helpful.

You can define a named volume within your `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: some_name
    image: mongo
    labels:
      com.docker.compose.project: app-name  
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongo_db:/data/db

volumes:
  mongo_db:
```

You could then use the `docker volume inspect` command to see some details about this volume.

```
docker volume inspect mongo_db
```